# Encog - Using Hybrid Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, encog

How is using simulated annealing in conjunction with a feed-forward neural network different than simply resetting the weights (and placing the hidden layer into a new error valley) when a local minimum is reached?  Is simulated annealing used by the FFNN as a more systematic way of moving the weights around to find a global minimum, and hence only **one iteration** is performed each time the validation error begins to increase relative to the training error... slowly moving the current position across the error function? In this case, the simulated annealing is independent of the feed-forward network and the the feed-forward network is dependent on the simulated annealing output. If not, and the simulated annealing is directly dependent on results from the FFNN, I don't see how the simulated annealing trainer would receive this information in terms of *how* to update its own weights (if that makes sense).  One of the examples mentions a *cycle* (multiple iterations), which doesn't fit into my first assumption.

I have looked at different exmaples, where network.fromArray() and network.toArray() are used, but I only see network.encodeToArray() and network.decodeFromArray(). What is the most current way (v3.2) to transfer weights from one type of network to another?  Is this the same for using genetic algorithms, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Neural network training algorithms, such as simulated annealing are essentially searches.  The weights of the neural network are essentially vector coordinates that specify a location in a high dimension space.

Consider hill-climbing, possibly the most simple training algorithm.  You adjust one weight, thus moving in one dimension and see if it improves your score.  If the score is improved, then great, stay there and try a different dimension next iteration.  If your score is NOT improved, retreat and try a different dimension next time.  Think of a human looking at every point they can reach in one step and choosing the step that increases their altitude the most.  If no step will increase altitude (you are standing in the middle of a valley), then your stuck. This is a local minimum.

Simulated annealing adds one critical component to hill-climbing.  We might move to a lesser a worse location.  (not greedy)  The probability that we will move to a lesser location is determined by the decreasing temperature.

If you look inside of the NeuralSimulatedAnnealing classes you will see calls to NetworkCODEC.NetworkToArray() and NetworkCODEC.ArrayToNetwork().  These are how the weight vector is directly updated.